# How to close a div,show image load and open another div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation, image-loading

I have two div in my page named div1 and div2 and a button.Initially div2 will be hidden.When i click on the button **three things should happen**

```
1.close the div1 with some animation
2.Show a loading image for a particular amt of time
3.Show the div2 with some animation
```

How can i implement the above using jquery ?

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not for question like "Please give me the code for X". Start coding, do some research, learn jQuery. Then when you get stuck somewhere in the implementing process we will be happy to assist you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="loading-image" style="display:none;"><img src="loader.gif"/></div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

$("#button").click(function(){

$("#div1").slideUp();
$("#loading-image").show();

setTimeout(function() {
$("#loading-image").hide();
           $("#div2").slideDown();

        }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, check this out.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/D9Nw6/1/

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on('click', function () {
        $('#loading').show();
        $('#one').slideUp(1000);
        $('#two').slideDown( "1000", function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $('#loading').hide();
        });        
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" />
<div id="one">Blue</div>
<div id="two">Red</div>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this:

CSS:

```
#div2,, #my-img {
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#my-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#div1').fadeOut();
    $('#my-img').fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#div2').fadeIn(); 
    }, 2000 );
}
```

What this basicly does is:

- You click on the button
- The first div dissappears and the image appears
- After 2 seconds (2000 miliseconds) the image disappears and the second div appears.

Answer (score 0):

If I had understood your question correctly, this code will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/dehisok/c6XCx/

```
$('#div1').fadeOut(500, function() {        
    $('body').append('<img src="http://ppt4web.ru/assets/2c736062/img/loading.gif" class="loading" width="100" />');

    $('#div2').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('.loading').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**close the div1 with some animation**

```
$('#div1').fadeOut('slow');
```

for more help [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

**Show a loading image for a particular amt of time**

```
$("#loadingDiv").show().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

**Show the div2 with some animation**

```
$('#div1').fadeIn('slow');
```

for more help [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)